# Unable to get a new line using \n in Confirmation Box

Tags: c#, javascript

Below is my code

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "{return ConfirmAction('You are about to Delete Order . Please Note \r\n  1. Order no longer can be retrieved \r\n 2. Changes to the order are not saved. \r\n Are you sure you wish to continue to Delete?')};");
```

I would like the Confirmation box to display the message with Yes and Cancel button as below:

You are about to Delete Order . Please Note:
1.Order no longer can be retrieved
2.Changes to the order are not saved
 Are you sure you wish to continue to Delete?

I tried "\n" , '\n' , and "\r\n" but still unable to insert lines.

Comment: What is `ConfirmAction`?

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes as Trevor indicated.  The sequence of \r\n vs \n is browser specific, so you may want to confirm what you target browser uses.  Several answers notes Environment.Newline.  You need to be aware that Environment.Newline is SERVER specific and will not change based on which browser is rendering your javascript.

Comment: "A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms," from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx.  If you can explain to me how Environment.Newline interrogates the browser in use and alters its output, I will withdraw my comment.

Comment: http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: Are you saying you can't run ASP.NET *nix with Mono?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a string in a string so you're going to need to escape the back slashes:

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "{return ConfirmAction('You are about to Delete Order . Please Note \\n  1. Order no longer can be retrieved \\n 2. Changes to the order are not saved. \\n Are you sure you wish to continue to Delete?')};");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the component you are using, but did you try `<br />`?
If it accepts HTML, that might work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String buttonString = "{return ConfirmAction('You are about to Delete Order . Please Note \r\n  1. Order no longer can be retrieved \r\n 2. Changes to the order are not saved. \r\n Are you sure you wish to continue to Delete?')};"
buttonString = buttonString.Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine);
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", buttonString);
```